# Looking for the software F(z) from lascaux graphics

Tags: complex-analysis, math-software

I know this is not a typical math question. I also thought about asking on superUser or stackoverflow but I came to the conclusion that I have a higher chance of getting an answer here on the math stackexchange.

I recently have read about the tool named f(z) from lascaux graphics which helps visualizing complex valued functions. This seems to be a very nice tool in complex analysis. 
However it looks a little bit outdated and I cant find anything like a website or something. 
Do you know this tool and/or have any idea where I can find additional information about it?

Comment: Have a look at http://mathfaculty.fullerton.edu/mathews/complex.html

Comment: I already visited this page. There is no information about where to get F(z). The links to lascaux software does not work